# Convergence in $L^2$ of $T_n/\mathbb{E} (T_n)\to 1$, $T_n$ be the first time a Galton Watson has more than $n$ individuals

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(N(t))_{t\geq 0}$ be a Galton-Watson process with reproduction law $p=(p_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and rate of births $\tau >0$ i.e. we start with one individual and each individual in the system gives birth indepently with rate $\tau $ to a random number of offsprings distributed as $p$. 
If $p_0=0$ and $m : = \sum_{n\geq 1}np_n > 1$ then the stopping time 
$$T_n := \inf\{t > 0\colon N(t) > n\}$$
is finite a.e.

I want to prove that $$\frac{T_n}{\mathbb{E}T_n} \to 1 \text{ in }L^2$$
for this I think we can use dominated convergence and prove first that we have the convergence a.e. and then prove that 
$$\sup_n \frac{T_n}{\mathbb{E}T_n} \in L^2$$
But I don't know how to do either of those things.

Any help and idea will be appreciated

Thanks